# Mongo db Group by, count with a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using Mongodb, I want to get the count of sensor values above 100 and sensorvalues below 100 for each particular region(group by region).

I have a sensorValue property and it has 4 sub properties namely.
1)sensorValue (the values will be 100, 200 122, 80 etc) - I want to know the count of above 100 and below 100 per region.
2)Latitude 
3)Longitude
4)Region (The name of the region) - I want the count with respect to this region.

With the help of stackoverflow, I wrote the below query.

```
getProximityIntervalRate = (req, res) => {
    console.log("entered1")
    this.model = ProximityLocation;
    const startDate = req.headers.startdate, endDate = req.headers.enddate;
    console.log(req.headers, startDate, endDate);
    // TODO: server validatoin

    this.model.aggregate([
        { $match: { 'observationTimestamp': { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lte: new Date(endDate) } } },
        {
            $project: {
                regoin: 1,
                lessthan: {
                    $cond: [{ $lt: ["$sensorValue.sensorValue", 5] }, 1, 0]
                },
                morethan: {
                    $cond: [{ $gt: ["$sensorValue.sensorValue", 5] }, 1, 0]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: { _id: { regoin: "$sensorValue.regoin" }, 
            countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThan" },
            countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThan" } uh
            }
        },

    ], (err, location) => {
        console.log('location', location);
        if (!location) { return res.sendStatus(404); }

        res.status(200).json(location);

    });

}
```

I am not sure how to address the subproperty "sensorValue.regoin" under the "$project" option.Please let me know if I am missing something.

[image: Sample Document is attached]

Comment: can you post a sample document?

Comment: in `$lessthan ` field, what do you get? and array right?

Comment: It is grouping by with respect to regions. But I am getting the CountSmaller and CountBigger Counts as 0. Please check the below results.

(2) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: {…}, countSmaller: 0, countBigger: 0}
1: {_id: {…}, countSmaller: 0, countBigger: 0}

Comment: @Saravana, Attached a sample document. Please check.

Comment: not in a snapshot, can you post a complete document in a formatted text?

Comment: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c2ce6d6ce1ab65796d9bda1"),
 "userAccount" : {
  "userId" : "110649669188178331701",
  "userEmail" : "abc@abc.org"
 },
 "deviceId" : "733265f82f64cb37",
 "sensorType" : "TYPE_Join_PROXIMITY_GPS",
 "sensorValue" : {
  "sensorValue" : "8",
  "attr_lat" : "53.290092",
  "attr_lng" : "-9.074288",
  "regoin" : "\"Dangan\""
 },
 "observationTimestamp" : ISODate("2019-01-02T14:26:20.998+00:00")
},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation to get the result

```
db.t66.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id : "$sensorValue.region", 
        lessThan : {$sum : {$cond: [{$lt : [{$toInt : "$sensorValue.sensorValue"}, 50]}, 1,0]}},
        greaterThan : {$sum : {$cond: [{$gte : [{$toInt : "$sensorValue.sensorValue"}, 50]}, 1,0]}},
    }}
])
```

you can remove `$toInt` if the `sensorValue` is `int` datatype

Comment: Thank you @Saravana. I am getting the lessthan and greaterThan count as a whole (but not region wise).

Comment: there is a typo in my query, should it be `region` or `regoin`

Comment: You are right. It worked after changing region from regoin. Thank you very much!